# Subplot from multi excels

Tags: python

I am dealing with 20 excels. For each excel, I do the same subsetting and plotting. I can get 20 separate figures now using for loop. But how can I put these figures in one subplot (5*4)? Check some posts but cannot get the answer.

```
for files in allfiles:
    #if re.search(r".*.xlsx", files):
        df = pd.read_excel("D:\Brown research\Task2 site selection\All_excel\{0}".format(files))  
        newdf = df[(df.slope != 0) & (df.AI >= 0.8) & (df.reach_len > 5000)]
        
        Q1=df['slope'].quantile(0.25)
        Q3=df['slope'].quantile(0.75)
        IQR=Q3-Q1
 
        Upper_Whisker = Q3+3*IQR
        newdf = newdf[newdf['slope']<Upper_Whisker]
        
        x = newdf['slope'] 
        y = newdf['AI']
        
        nbins = 20
        plt.figure()
        plt.hist2d(x,y,nbins,cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, cmin=1)
        plt.colorbar()
        plt.title(files.split('_')[0],x=0.5,y=0.9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your fig and axes ahead of time and use matplotlib's object-oriented interface:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pandas

basedir = Path(r"D:\Brown research\Task2 site selection\All_excel")
fig, axes = pyplot.subplots(5, 4, figsize=(10, 10))

for xlfile, ax in zip(basedir.glob("*.xlsx"), axes.flat):
    df = pandas.read_excel(xlfile) 
    Q1=df['slope'].quantile(0.25)
    Q3=df['slope'].quantile(0.75)
    IQR=Q3-Q1
    Upper_Whisker = Q3+3*IQR
    
    newdf = df.loc[lambda df: 
        (df["slope"] != 0) &
        (df["slope"] < Upper_Whisker) &
        (df["AI"] >= 0.8) &
        (df["reach_len"] > 5000) 
    ]
    x = newdf['slope'] 
    y = newdf['AI']
    nbins = 20
    hist = ax.hist2d(x,y,nbins,cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, cmin=1)
    fig.colorbar(hist)
    ax.set_title(xlfile.stem.split('_')[0], x=0.5, y=0.9)
```

This assumes that you have exactly 20 files in your directory.

Better yet, I would concat everything into a single dataframe would use seaborn to build up the plot dynamically:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pandas
import seaborn

def get_upper_whisker(df, column):
    Q1 = df[column].quantile(0.25)
    Q3 = df[column].quantile(0.75)
    IQR = Q3 - Q1
    return Q3 + (3 * IQR)

basedir = Path(r"D:\Brown research\Task2 site selection\All_excel")
data = pandas.concat([
    pandas.read_excel(xlfile).assign(file=xlfile.stem)
    for xlfile in basefir.glob("*.xlsx")
])

fig = (
    data.groupby("file")
        .apply(lambda g: 
            g.loc[g["slope"] < get_upper_whisker(g, "slope")]
        )
        .loc[lambda df:
            (df["slope"] != 0) &
            (df["AI"] >= 0.8) &
            (df["reach_len"] > 5000)     
        ]
        .pipe(seaborn.FacetGrid, col="file", col_wrap=4)
)
fig.map(pyplot.hist2d, "slope", "AI", bins=20, cmap=pyplot.cm.coolwarm, cmin=1)
```

Comment: Thank you. For the first method, I got the "'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_array'". The second one works!

Comment: I prefer to use method 1. Could anyone help to get the correct colorbar?

Comment: @BoWang did you try, `fig.add_legend`?

Comment: Thanks. I found that just need to revise a little bit, e.g., "fig.colorbar(hist[3],ax=ax)". hist[3] is the "image".

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the two solutions from @Paul H. For solution 1, just need to revise a little bit, e.g.,  "fig.colorbar(hist[3],ax=ax)". hist[3] is the "image".